# How to get the class type in a inherited shared method

Tags: vb.net, class

Folks;

Code looks like:

```
Public Class MasterA
  Inherits Underling
End Class

Public Class MasterB
  Inherits Underling
End Class

Public Mustinherit Class Underling
  Sub DoSomething()
    Me.GetType 'Using the instance, I can get the class.
  end sub
  Shared function() as ???? 'How can I define the return type based on the class that inherited me?
    'Me.GetType 'Won't work as this is a shared function with no instance 'Me'
  End Function
End class
```

OK.  The question is: is there a way to get at the class type from within a shared function that was inherited by another class?

What I'm building is an XML serializer/desrializer as an inheritable class so that classes that inherit it can be serilized to an XML file, and back again.  Rather than writing a serializer/deserializer for each type of class I want to do this with, I'd like to just inherit the functionality.

To do that, though, requires that I be able to ascertain the clas that inherited me in the shared function.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the desired behavior with a generic base class, my VB is a little rusty so you might find stray parens or brackets. This would really be the only way to get a type reference to an inheriting class in a shared base class function.

```
Public Mustinherit Class Underling(Of T)
  Sub DoSomething()
    Me.GetType 'Using the instance, I can get the class.
  end sub
  Shared function() As T
    ' GetType(T)  should get the type at this point
  End Function
End class

Public Class MasterA
  Inherits Underling(Of MasterA)
End Class

Public Class MasterB
  Inherits Underling(Of MasterB)
End Class
```

As a side note it does seem like a rather weird solution to handle `XmlSerialization` rather than through your own serializer implementation or [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)